# R How to export my results in multiple rasters layers at the same time?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, lapply, raster

As a first step, I import a table that contains daily data for several sampling stations (see sample below).
Subsequently, I will want to create raster layers for each date (day) and export these rasters later with different names.
As I have a long time series (40 years) with daily data, I wish to make a loop (see my program below) but I can not give different names to the output rasters. So every time he crushes me the previous layer.
I am new to loop programming, can you help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

```
data=read.table(file="data.csv", sep=";", header=TRUE)
head(data)
LAMBX   LAMBY   DATE    S
600 24010   20180801    15.3
600 24010   20180802    12
600 24010   20180803    15
600 24010   20180804    14.8
600 24010   20180805    16.8
600 24010   20180806    15.1
601 24011   20180801    11
601 24011   20180802    14
601 24011   20180803    16.8
601 24011   20180804    15.1
601 24011   20180805    13.8
601 24011   20180806    12.7
602 24012   20180801    15.3
602 24012   20180802    14
602 24012   20180803    12
602 24012   20180804    16.8
602 24012   20180805    17.5
602 24012   20180806    15.1


library(dplyr)
library(sp)
library(raster)
# for each date I will do the following manipulations
for (i in data[,"DATE"]) {
# to delimit my study area
  table=filter(data, DATE == i & LAMBX %in% 601:602 & LAMBY %in% 24011:24012) 
# convert geographic coordinates
  table[,c("LAMBX", "LAMBY")]= 100*table[,c("LAMBX", "LAMBY")]

# spatialize the stations
  xy <- table[,c("LAMBX", "LAMBY")]
  sptable <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = xy, data = table,
                                 proj4string = CRS("+proj=lcc +lat_1=46.8 +lat_0=46.8 +lon_0=0 +k_0=0.99987742 +x_0=600000 +y_0=2200000 +a=6378249.2 +b=6356515 +towgs84=-168,-60,320,0,0,0,0 +pm=paris +units=m +no_defs"))

# rasterize my SpatialPointsDataFrame
  rsptable <- rasterFromXYZ(as.data.frame(sptable)[, c("LAMBX", "LAMBY","S")],  crs="+proj=lcc +lat_1=46.8 +lat_0=46.8 +lon_0=0 +k_0=0.99987742 +x_0=600000 +y_0=2200000 +a=6378249.2 +b=6356515 +towgs84=-168,-60,320,0,0,0,0 +pm=paris +units=m +no_defs")
  # export my rasters layers
  writeRaster(rsptable, filename="S_date.tif", format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: I see `T_Q` in the code. Is it in your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a `T_Q` variable in your data so I'm going to use `S` instead. They trick is to create an empty list object that fill at each loop iteration. Then you can create a *stack* of the result. Each layer of the stack is an individual date.

```
library(dplyr)
library(sp)
library(raster)

data <- read.table(text = "
LAMBX   LAMBY   DATE    S
600 24010   20180801    15.3
600 24010   20180802    12
600 24010   20180803    15
600 24010   20180804    14.8
600 24010   20180805    16.8
600 24010   20180806    15.1
601 24011   20180801    11
601 24011   20180802    14
601 24011   20180803    16.8
601 24011   20180804    15.1
601 24011   20180805    13.8
601 24011   20180806    12.7
602 24012   20180801    15.3
602 24012   20180802    14
602 24012   20180803    12
602 24012   20180804    16.8
602 24012   20180805    17.5
602 24012   20180806    15.1", header = TRUE)

crs_string <- "+proj=lcc +lat_1=46.8 +lat_0=46.8 +lon_0=0 +k_0=0.99987742 +x_0=600000 +y_0=2200000 +a=6378249.2 +b=6356515 +towgs84=-168,-60,320,0,0,0,0 +pm=paris +units=m +no_defs"

res <- list()
for (i in seq_along(unique(data[,"DATE"]))){
  table <- filter(data,
                  DATE == unique(data[,"DATE"])[i] &
                  LAMBX %in% 601:602 &
                  LAMBY %in% 24011:24012)
  table[,c("LAMBX", "LAMBY")] <-  100 * table[,c("LAMBX", "LAMBY")]

  xy       <- table[,c("LAMBX", "LAMBY")]
  sptable  <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = xy, data = table,
                                    proj4string = CRS(crs_string))
  rsptable <- rasterFromXYZ(
    as.data.frame(sptable)[, c("LAMBX", "LAMBY","S")],  crs = crs_string)
  res[[i]] <- rsptable
}

res <- stack(res)
writeRaster(res, filename="S_date.tif", format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much jsta . The routine works perfectly